# Does the "--full-refresh" tag in dbt carry over to parent/children models?

Tags: dbt

I am running the following command `dbt run -s +model --full-refresh` where some of the parent models are also incremental tables.

I am not sure if `--full-refresh` is also applied to the parent incremental models or do they run incrementally?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The `full-refresh` option is applied to the `run` command, which includes all of the models you specify with the `-s` option. This includes any parent or child models that are picked up when using a `+` modifier.

The exception to this is if you have a `full_refresh` option set to false in the model config.

```
models:
  [<resource-path>](resource-path):
    +full_refresh: false
```

or

```
{{ config(
    full_refresh = false
) }}

select ...
```

> If specified as true or false, the full_refresh config will take precedence over the presence or absence of the --full-refresh flag.

Ref: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/full_refresh